# Android Scrolling and scaling in a layout

Tags: android, graphics, zooming, scale, drag

I want to have a UI which draws some graphics items and users can scroll and scale the graphics scene with gestures(like Google maps).I have used graphics framework in Qt but I can't find anything like it in Android.

I fond [Dragging and Scaling](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html) and sample **InteractiveChart** in Developer, but it seems complicated.I tried to realize by mysely.Here is some snippet.I use ScaleGestureDetector and GestureDetector to change the parameter of mContent,the mContent is a FrameLayout.It's functional but have some bugs.I want some advice, thanks!!

```
private final ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener mScaleGestureListener
        = new ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();//This value is defined as (getCurrentSpan() / getPreviousSpan())
        float factor = scaleFactor / lastScaleFactor;
        Log.d(TAG, "factor+" + factor);
        lastScaleFactor=scaleFactor;
        scale*= factor;
        mContent.setScaleX(scale);
        mContent.setScaleY(scale);

        return super.onScale(detector);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mContent.setPivotX(detector.getFocusX());
        mContent.setPivotY(detector.getFocusY());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        lastScaleFactor=1;
    }
};

private final GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener mGestureListener
        = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        mContent.scrollBy((int)distanceX,(int)distanceY);
        return true;
    }
};
```